# How to run 2 different Jenkins account on same Mac machine at the same time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Mac machine for Jenkins servers. I have 2 different ports for Jenkins servers but both the ports open same Jenkins server profile. I want to run 2 different Jenkins servers on these ports at the same time.
I use the following command in terminal to start Jenkins.

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpListenAddress='ip address'  --httpPort='port'
```

How should I achieve this?

Comment: @IanW how to have 2 different JENKINS_HOME env variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have hoped a Mac user replied, but this seems similar to Linux, where the best approach is two separate accounts.

However, at the most basic level, you need two different directories, launching using two different [JENKINS_HOME](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/administering+jenkins) via ENV or parameter ; that's where the data, jobs plugins, configuration, etc. is. Default is in the home directory unless you override.

Setting an environment variable is also similar to Linux. In different Terminal windows for each instance, `export JENKINS_HOME=/path/to/dir`, the run java command. May be more convenient to wrap the two commands in a batch file and run that.

There are Mac specific [references](https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/) for [Homebrew](https://www.macminivault.com/installing-jenkins-on-macos/) and for the deprecated [OSX installer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer).

The main thing is just to determine where to set and pass different [initial settings](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/): `--httpPort=8180` values for your separate directories, as well as separate ports, You can also pass `--prefix=/<<value>>` so you can have `${HOSTNAME}:${JENKINS_PORT}${JENKINS_PREFIX}`

ie:
`java -${JAVA_OPTIONS} -DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins/data -jar /path/to/jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins_A --httpPort=8180`